# Create a dictionary based on colums of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                   'col2': ['A','A','B','C','D','D']}, 
                   index=['row1', 'row2','row3', 'row4','row5', 'row6'])
```

I would like to create the following dictionary based on the values of the dataframe df:

```
dict = {'A':[1,2], 'B':[3], 'C':[4], 'D':[5,6]}
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert values of `col1` per groups by [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to lists and then call [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('col2')['col1'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3], 'C': [4], 'D': [5, 6]}
```